# Where's the best place get smart contract development help, quickly?

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development

I've tried gitter. It take like 3 hours get to get help.

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum stack exchange community is big with a huge amount of learners and people looking into mastering their skills and gaining knowledge. If you ask a good and specific question you can get help very quickly.

---

*It all depends on your particular problem and how you ask a question.*

---

Please follow the rules of community:

- [How do I ask a good question?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
- [Be nice.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)